# Using multiple inputs at once

Tags: python, python-3.x

Right now my program takes an input and gives a single line output. This program basically uses a manually installed python library called network-x (that creates and analyses graphs and has many built-in graph-theory related functions).

For this specific program, it takes an input as shown below:

```
6       <-- Order of the graph (i.e the graph has 0 to 5 vertices)
1 2 3   <-- vertices going out from 0
2       <-- vertices going out from 1
3 5     <-- vertices going out from 2
4       <-- vertices going out from 3
5       <-- vertices going out from 4
        <-- vertices going out from 5 (no vertices going out from 5)
```

and returns the output (that states how many connected-components the graph has):

```
1
```

Another example of an input:

```
6
3 5
2

4

4
```

and output:

```
2
```

The source code for my program is:

```
import networkx as nx
import sys
def main():     
 dag = nx.Graph()
 order = int(input())
 for i in range (order):
      dag.add_node(i)
 for j in range(order):
      seq = [input()]
      for vertex in seq:
           vertexList = vertex.split()
           for element in vertexList:
                dag.add_edge(j,int(element))
      j+=1

 components = nx.number_connected_components(dag)
 print (components)
main()
```

I am currently stuck on figuring how to make the program take **both of these input at once and compute a 2 line output (each line outputting results for each input)** as shown below:

```
6
1 2 3
2
3 5
4
5

6
3 5 
2

4

4
0 <-- when the the user inputs a zero, the loop terminates
```

after the loop terminates it outputs:

```
1
2
```

Any help would be appreciated.
P.S.if you want to install the network-x library visit network-x's github website: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/install.html

Comment: Put your `main` function in a loop, store `components` in a list, exit when `order` equals `0`, and output the `components` list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a loop and save each result in a `list`:

```
def main():
    result = []

    while 1:
        dag = nx.Graph()
        order = int(input())
        if not order: # check if it's 0
            break # end the loop
        for i in range (order):
            dag.add_node(i)
        for j in range(order):
            vertexList = input().split() # no need to put this single string into a list
            for element in vertexList:
                dag.add_edge(j,int(element))
        result.append(nx.number_connected_components(dag))

    print (result)
```

I've removed the unnecessary `[input()]`, which produced a single-element `list` that you loop over. There's no need to make a loop to access a single object. I also removed the `j += 1` at the end of the loop with `j`, because all that does is reassign a new value right before it gets the next one from the `range` object anyway. It wasn't doing anything.